# Dynamically outputting content from an object to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a header object with the keys classes and buttonContent, please help me figure out how to dynamically generate a button with a class from the classes object and content from the buttonContent object (instead of 123)

```
{type: 'header', classes: ['1','2','3','4'], buttonContent: ['link 1','link 2','link 3','link 4',]},

function header(content) {
    const html = content.buttonContent.map((item =>
        `<button onclick="document.location='${item}'"> 123 </button>`));

    return `
    <header>
        <img src="#" alt="foto" title="foto">
        <nav>
            ${html.join('')}
        </nav>
        <button class="burger-menu">menu</button>
    </header>`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By using both arrays (classes and buttonContent) in a synchronous way**

```
function header(content) {
    const html = content.buttonContent.map((item, index) =>
        `<button class="${content.classes[index] || ''}" onclick="document.location='#'">${item}</button>`
    );

    return `
    <header>
        <img src="#" alt="foto" title="foto">
        <nav>
            ${html.join('')}
        </nav>
        <button class="burger-menu">menu</button>
    </header>`;
}

const content = {
    type: 'header', 
    classes: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    buttonContent: ['link 1', 'link 2', 'link 3', 'link 4'],
};

document.body.innerHTML = header(content);
```